# Reading a table with different syntax for each row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I'm trying to do something as simple as read a .csv file.

The file contains rows written in 3 different ways.

```
"00001","Some text - and a number - 99999999","2020-01-01","Some more text","9999"
"00002",""Some text, with a separator and a number - 9999999"","2020-01-01","Some more text","9999"
"00003","Some text (and a number) - 99999999","2020-01-01",""Again, a separator"","9999"
"00013",""Comp, which does something - 999999999"","2020-01-01","Standard rgb","r k å g","","","","15","Fak E","XXX","XXX","2020-01-01","E","","","EKT","0.00","15.26","E","Å","","0","9","52"
```

Doing,

```
pd.read_csv(path, encoding='UTF-8-sig', header=None)
```

results in the following table. I want all rows to be like the first.

[image]

I've also tried providing `quotechar='"'`.
I have absolutely no say in how this .csv file is written and rewriting in Excel or N++ is not a suitable solution. I use encoding UTF-8-sig because of scandinavian letters in the real files, but removing doesn't do anything anyways.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Preprocess the data/file before feeding it to pandas to make each line uniform.

Answer (score 1):

Preprocess prior to feeding to Pandas. Use regex to replace doublequotes whith single quotes.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

#simulate a file  
s = '''"00001","Some text - and a number - 99999999","2020-01-01","Some more text","9999"
"00002",""Some text, with a separator and a number - 9999999"","2020-01-01","Some more text","9999"
"00003","Some text (and a number) - 99999999","2020-01-01",""Again, a separator"","9999"'''

f = io.StringIO(s)

pattern = r'""'
# in memory "file" instead of writing the change to disk
g = io.StringIO(re.sub(pattern,'"',f.read()))
df = pd.read_csv(g, quotechar='"', header=None, dtype=object, encoding='UTF-8-sig')
```

---

If the file is `test.csv` and you don't want/need to write the modified data back to disk.

```
import io
import re
import pandas as pd

pattern = r'""'
with open('test.csv') as f:
    g = io.StringIO(re.sub(pattern,'"',f.read()))

df = pd.read_csv(g, quotechar='"', header=None, dtype=object, encoding='UTF-8-sig')
```

If you want to modify the file and write it to disk before using it with pandas.

```
import io
import re
import pandas as pd

pattern = r'""'
with open('test.csv') as f, open('modified.csv','w') as g:
    g.write(re.sub(pattern,'"',f.read()))

df = pd.read_csv('modified.csv', quotechar='"', header=None, dtype=object, encoding='UTF-8-sig')
```

---

If `test.csv` looks like

```
"00013",""Comp, which does something - 999999999"","2020-01-01","Standard rgb","r k å g","","","","15","Fak E","XXX","XXX","2020-01-01","E","","","EKT","0.00","15.26","E","Å","","0","9","52"
```

Then I can only see a way to normalize it by parsing twice - first replace quoted empty strings with doublequoted empty strings, then replace all doublequotes with single quotes.

```
pattern1 = r',("")(?=,)'
pattern2 = r'""'

with open('test.csv') as f:
    data = re.sub(pattern1,',"\1"',f.read())
    g = io.StringIO(re.sub(pattern2,',"\1",',data))

df = pd.read_csv(g, quotechar='"', header=None, dtype=object, encoding='UTF-8-sig')
```

It ends up with those *wierd* null string characters -

```
>>> print(df.to_string())
       0    1  2     3                                  4  5    6           7             8         9  10 11 12  13     14   15   16          17 18 19 20   21    22     23 24  25 26 27 28  29
0  00013"  NaN    Comp   which does something - 999999999    NaN  2020-01-01  Standard rgb  r k Ã¥ g        15  Fak E  XXX  XXX  2020-01-01  E      EKT  0.00  15.26  E  Ã…    0  9  52
>>>
```

---

Maybe someone can come up with a better regular expression pattern.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. Keeping the commas that are inside the extra quotes was what I needed. 
Just an extra question: Now I need to copy all lines in the .csv into s to get the triple-quotes around it. Lets say I have a test.csv, how would I then proceed?

Comment: `...copy all lines in the .csv into s` - no I was just simulating a file so that my example/solution could be copied straight from the answer and executed. See my edit for working with the file directly.

Comment: Hi again, thank you so much for helping me. 
Something seems to be lost from the simulation part and the part with test.csv. 
Now the the split is not split correctly, some of the string thats supposed to go in column 2 now goes in column 1

Comment: More exactly, a string like the following works with the simulation procedure but not when loaded from test.csv. 

`'''00013,"Comp, which does something - 999999999",2020-01-01,Standard rgb,r k å g,,,,15,Fak E,XXX,XXX,2020-01-01,E,,,EKT,0.00,15.26,E,Å,,0,9,52'''`

Comment: @ChristofferSannes I put the example data from your question in a file and it works just fine. If your example data is not representative of the actual you should revise it - please read [mre].

Comment: I actually thought I did. But I apologize for my noobishness. If you have the time I would really appreciate if you could have a look at a procedure for the new example.

Comment: @ChristofferSannes - the data in your question has not changed - there is no *new example*.

Comment: sorry! I put it in the comment section, but now it's also in the question text.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a Pandas issue. Using corrected data:

```
pd.read_csv('/home/aklaver/csv_test.txt', encoding='UTF-8-sig',  header=None)
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 2, saw 6
```

Using Python csv module directly:

```
with open('/home/aklaver/csv_test.txt', newline='') as csvfile:
    r = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in r:
        print(', '.join(row))

00001, Some text - and a number - 99999999, 2020-01-01, Some more text,  "9999"
00002, Some text,  with a separator and a number - 9999999"", 2020-01-01, Some more text, 9999
00003, Some text (and a number) - 99999999, 2020-01-01, Again,  a separator"", 9999
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your submission. This isn't exactly what I want however, as this splits Some text, with a separator and a number - 9999999 into Some text, AND with a separator and a number - 9999999. I would like the whole string to be kept as one.

Comment: That is down to the double quoting of some of the text. Can you put the original data back up?